# How to restrict special character on input field with underscore allowed?

Tags: html, pattern-matching

> I am using this pattern for blocking the special character
>   [!@#$%^&*(),.?":{}|<>] but i want to allow underscore on input field
>
> This is the function which checking the special character onblur

```
function blockSpecialChar(e){
               var k;
               document.all ? k = e.keyCode : k = e.which;

        return ((k > 64 && k < 91) || (k > 96 && k < 123) || k == 8 || k == 32 || (k >= 48 && k <= 57));

        }
```

Comment: So what is the problem? Adding `_` to the char class? `[!@#$%^&*(),.?":{}|<>_]`?

Comment: Please tag your question with `regex`, it is not a pattern matching but a regex problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The keycode for underscore in javascript is 95. You could add `|| (k == 95)` to the return in your blackSpecialChar function to allow underscores.